# Is there a way to have multiple main in the Visual studio?

Tags: visual-studio-2010

Is there a way to have multiple main in the project and each main can be executed?

Comment: Main: I do not think it means what you think it means.

Comment: No there is only one main, but you can start new threads. What are you trying to do?

Comment: Java permit multiple main in the project.

Comment: Well perhaps Oracle has a patent on multiple main functions inside one project and Microsoft doesn't want to license it.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to multi-thread your application, you should look into thread libraries. Otherwise, there is no way you can have multiple main functions. The compiler stores the main function as the first set of instructions to be executed. If you are just running one thread, you can't simultaneously execute two sets of the same instructions. What exactly are you trying to do?